# How do I download a public dataset from the internet to linux?

Tags: linux, download, bioinformatics

I need to download a public dataset (from OpenNeuro) online to linux so I can work with this data. How to do so?

Comment: You probably want to look at either curl -o <filename> <url>, or wget <url>, either of those will most likly work, although the exact command can vary depending on the url or site.

Comment: What is OpenNeuro, what is a dataset and where it is hosted? You will need to give more details to get help. Maybe not everyone here is aware of the resources you are trying to use...

Answer (score 1):

The methods of downloading are as varied as the number of sites people download from. For OpenNeuro specifically, each dataset has a download link associated with it, and possibly commands to download from S3 that may or may not work for you. Again, specific to OpenNeuro, you need to use Chrome, and simply click the download links for the dataset you're interested in. They explicitly do not support Firefox for downloading.

Comment: Possibly from the file is too big, but the download button isn't working. I let it sit (acting like it's downloading) for a couple days and then gave up on that method. For S3, do I need to download AWS or how do I go about that?